# HTML5 video not working in Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, html5-video

Hi I started use html5 video tag on some webs maybe in November 2016. After application on every webs, videos work correct on everyone browser on pc/notebook and browsers on android/iOS (especially Chrome on both system and tested in Safari in iOS).
Maybe week ago client report me "video not work on my tablet and mobile". When I search he has android with Chrome. When I test it on my android mobile, than video not work in Chrome. But in Firefox everything ok, in Opera mini video only show and after click on it video run pop up window with question, if I would like to download video or run in this pop up window. When I test it by emulation in Chrome on pc then video work. If I resize Chrome browser on pc to mobile width/height, than video work.
I try test add another type of video (I used mp4 for that i try add ogg and one another tame i mean webm) but nothing change.

I mean there is some problem in update of Android Chrome. In version 54 they stop autoplay of video. I mean here is some bug, but I don't know why they "kill" atribute "poster" which show picture if isn't video aviable..

Have someone way how I can repair this?

Web where I used HTML5 video: [here](http://www.plastove-sklepy.cz/)

Code:

```
//CSS part
.blok_video_home{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #626262;
  overflow: hidden;
}
video#bgvid {
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  /*-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);*/
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  width: auto;
  z-index: 0;
}
.no-borderradius video#bgvid {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
    }
.pozadi_bez_videa{
  background-size: cover !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center center !important;
  background-image: url("../../img/bg-video-home.jpg") !important;
}

//HTML part (here i have image in "poster" but now I try delete him and try make it via CSS class ".pozadi_bez_videa" which add same image to background
  <div class="blok_video_home">
    <video autoplay loop poster="" id="bgvid" preload="auto"></video> <?php /* poster="img/bg-video.jpg" */ ?>
  </div>

  //jQuery part (to this "ifs" code enter on mobile, but I mean not add this <source> on mobile Chorme on android...
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var min_sirka_1280 = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1280px)");
  if (min_sirka_1280.matches) {
    $("#bgvid").html('<source src="video/sklepy_1080p_web_11_2016.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' );
  }

  var min_sirka_1000 = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1000px)");
  var max_sirka_1000 = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1279px)");
  if ( (min_sirka_1000.matches)&&(max_sirka_1000.matches) ) {
    $("#bgvid").html('<source src="video/sklepy_720p_web_11_2016.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' );
  }

  var min_sirka_700 = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 700px)");
  var max_sirka_700 = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 999px)");
  if ( (min_sirka_700.matches)&&(max_sirka_700.matches) ) {
    $("#bgvid").html('<source src="video/sklepy_720p_web_11_2016.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' );
  }

  var min_sirka_500 = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 500px)");
  var max_sirka_500 = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 699px)");
  if ( (min_sirka_500.matches)&&(max_sirka_500.matches) ) {
    $("#bgvid").html('<source src="video/sklepy_394p_web_11_2016.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>' );
  }

  var sirka_okna = parseInt($(window).width());
  if ( sirka_okna <= 499 ) {
    $("#bgvid").css("display","none");
    $("#bgvid").hide();
    $(".blok_video_home").addClass("pozadi_bez_videa");
  }else{
    $(".blok_video_home").removeClass("pozadi_bez_videa");
  }
});
```

I search solution maybe two days but nothing. Can anyone help?

Comment: What's an android version on tested device?

Comment: Client has Chrome 54 on Android (Marshmallow) browser size 632x1280px ; I have Chrome 55 on Android (KitKat) browser size 320x570px

Comment: autoplay is problematic on mobile devices. Try to make the video muted (add `muted` attribute)

Comment: Giladd: Hi your tip is good. With "muted" video now works on my mobile (Chrome 55 on Android (KitKat) ), but on mobile of friends still not work.... On tablet of friend still not work.